# How to create a folder during xslt transformation with Saxon in which to copy binary data afterwards

Tags: java, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I'm currently in the process of writing an XSLT Stylesheet that will handle the transformation of DOCX Documents to (X)HTML files.

Given the fact images are either included (in the /word/media folder of the unzipped DOCX archive) or referenced from the file system I have to copy them from their given source location to the output folder of the transformation that is specified with a parameter in an external configuration file.

Actually using pure XSLT that won't be possible, however, the PE and EE versions of the Saxon XSLT processor offer the possibility to call reflexive java extension functions ( see http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensibility/functions/) which allows the execution of file/file system operations from within the context of the XSLT stylesheet.

What I have so far is this: I can grap the files from their given source location and copy them to the desired output folder. I adapted the approach described by Stefan Krause here: http://www.oxygenxml.com/archives/xsl-list/201011/msg00051.html.

However, this only works when the output folder is already present. If not the Java function(s) produces an error message.

So what I want now is to create the output folder at the beginning of the transformation, somehow like that:

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <!-- the reflexive java function that creates the output dir gets called -->
      <xsl:value-of select="java:mkdirs($base-path,$dir)" />
    </xsl:template>
```

Here would be the java:mkdirs function (in an external file) I have so far which, however, doesn't work.

```
    <xsl:stylesheet 
      version    = "2.0"
      xmlns:xs   = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:xsl  = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"

      xmlns:java      = "http://www.java.com"
      xmlns:java-uri  = "java.net.URI"
      xmlns:java-file = "java.io.File">

      <!-- reflexive java function to create a folder -->
      <xsl:function name="java:mkdirs">
        <xsl:param    name="base-path" as = "xs:string" />
        <xsl:param    name="dir"       as = "xs:string" />
        <xsl:variable name="full-path" as = "xs:string" select = "concat($base-path,'/',$dir)" />
        <xsl:variable name="new-dir" select="java-file:new(java-uri:new($full-path))" />
        <xsl:sequence select="java-file:mkdirs($new-dir)" /> 
      </xsl:function>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the functions you need are all in the EXPath file module, available with Saxon 9.5 (PE and higher editions). You don't need to write your own. See http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/expath-file

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I plan to provide these functionality by means of the EXPath functions as soon as the next Oxygen Editor update includes the new Saxon PE/EE 9.5 version. However, I also have/want to make the stylesheet backward compatible with older Saxon PE/EE versions and as far as I understand there would be no other way than using the reflexive Java functions.